# python number of points a certain point is adjacent to

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of coordinates, for example `[[1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1]]`, and for each point, I want to find the number of points either horizontally or vertically adjacent for that point, and then print out that number. So for the example, my programming will print:

```
1 #1, 0 is vertically adjacent to 1, 1
2 #1, 1 is vertically adjacent to 1, 0 and horizontally adjacent to 0, 1
1 #0, 1 is horizontally adjacent to 1, 1
```

Thanks for any help!

P.S. is there a way this can be done in O(N)?

Comment: here is an answer to the question you deleted about getting the index of the fraction to increment: https://replit.com/@ShashSinha/RareEmotionalDemoware#main.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other solution solves your *exact* problem, but a more general solution where the points can have arbitrary values would be:

```
def adjacent(a, b):
    '''
    Returns True if a and b are adjacent points
    '''
    if a[0] == b[0] and abs(a[1] - b[1]) == 1:
        return True 
    elif a[1] == b[1] and abs(a[0] - b[0]) == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return None 
coords = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1]] 
coords = [tuple(point) for point in coords]
result = {tuple(coord): [point for point in coords if adjacent(coord, point) and coord != point] for coord in coords}
print(result)
# {(1, 0): [(1, 1)], (1, 1): [(1, 0), (0, 1)], (0, 1): [(1, 1)]}
```

Although this omits the process of writing `is horizontally adjacent to` and `is vertically adjacent to`, it provides a dictionary which maps each coordinate to a list of all of it's adjacent pairs.

We can rewrite this to omit duplicate calculations:

```
def adjacent(a, b):
    '''
    Returns True if a and b are adjacent points
    '''
    if a[0] == b[0] and abs(a[1] - b[1]) == 1:
        return True 
    elif a[1] == b[1] and abs(a[0] - b[0]) == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return None 
coords = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1]] 
coords = [tuple(point) for point in coords]
result = {coords[i]: [point for point in coords[i+1:] if adjacent(coords[i], point)] for i in range(len(coords)- 1)}
print(result)
# {(1, 0): [(1, 1)], (1, 1): [(0, 1)]}
```

Note that this is the absolute minimum number of comparisons that we can achieve: we have to *at least* compare the first element to the next n-1, then the second element to the next n-2, then the third element to the next n-3, ... then the last element to the last 0 (we make no comparison here). In that case, you are doing 0 + 1 + 2 + ... n-2 + n-1 comparisons. This is equal to (1/2) * (n-1) * n, which is simply called O(n^2) so no, this cannot be done in O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Can be computed in O(N) as follows.

**Code**

```
def neighbors(point, set_pts = set((x,y) for x, y in data)):
    '''
        Computes neighbors of point in O(1) time
        Default argument set_pts is O(N) be is calculated only once i.e.
           the first time the function is read by the Pyton interpreter
    '''
    # Starting Message
    x, y = point
    start = f'#{x}, {y} is '
    
    # Check horizontal and vertical neighbor of point O(1)
    adjacents = []
    if y == 0 and (x, 1) in set_pts:
        adjacents.append(f' is vertically  adjacent to {x}, {1}')
    if y == 1 and (x, 0) in set_pts:
        adjacents.append(f' is vertically  adjacent to {x}, {0}')
    if x == 0 and (1, y) in set_pts:
        adjacents.append(f' is horizontally adjacent to {1}, {y}')
    if x == 1 and (0, y) in set_pts:
        adjacents.append(f' is horizontally adjacent to {0}, {y}')
        
    return start + ' and '.join(adjacents)

for pt in data:
    # N Points in loop, neigbors call takes O(1) so O(N) loop overall
    print(neighbors(pt))
```

**Output**

```
#1, 0 is  is vertically  adjacent to 1, 1
#1, 1 is  is vertically  adjacent to 1, 0 and  is horizontally adjacent to 0, 1
#0, 1 is  is horizontally adjacent to 1, 1
```